# Display entities like PERSON and GPE in nltk ne_chunk

Tags: python, nltk

```
def test():
    sample = "hello my name is Shefali and I live in Nebraska."
    print sample
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
    tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
    chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences)

    print(list(chunked_sentences))
```

the output is:

> hello my name is Shefali and I live in Nebraska.
>   [Tree('S', [('hello', 'NN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('name', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), Tree('PERSON', [('Shefali', 'NNP')]), ('and', 'CC'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('live', 'VBP'), ('in', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('Nebraska', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])]

When I write `print(chunked_sentences)`, it gives me the following output:`<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000CE18438>`  I want to extract only the PERSON and GPE out and print them. How do i do that? And what is the generator object?

Comment: You can try to filter from the result ? Generators are simple functions which return an iterable set of items, one at a time, in a special way. so the Generator compute values and forget on the fly. You have to iterate over the result of generator and so when you do list(result) then you are using list iterator.

Comment: how do i filter? some code would help!

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work,

```
for sent in chunked_sentences:
    for chunk in sent:
        if hasattr(chunk, "label") and chunk.label() == "PERSON":
            print(chunk)
```

This example is for Person, for GPE change the label.